# Installation stopped at "Configuring Target System"

Tags: 11.10, installation

Can't install on an old Pentium 4 with 1GB RAM

I started installing 11.10 and it stopped while "Configuring Target system". What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/820485.

You can try the following options as suggested:

1. Instead of starting Live and then installing, select "Install Ubuntu Now"
2. Do not select the "Download Updates while installing" option.

Comment: Using these options worked from me.

Answer (score 0):

Either enable your internet connection or uncheck the "Enable Networking" checkbox in the network menu (top right) during installation.